# Is there any Microsoft Office alternative?

Tags: microsoft-office, presentation, word-documents

I'm having trouble viewing and editing my documents in Ubuntu that I created using Microsoft Office in windows. Is there any way I can open, view and edit my document in both Windows and Ubuntu without any format being altered?

Comment: I've been using `LibreOffice` to edit and save MS Office documents with pretty good luck.

Comment: I've been using it too but the format doesn't seem exactly similar.

Comment: If you are concerned with formatting, non free alternative is to use online office.com or use Chrome Office app from Microsoft, all accessible from Ubuntu.

Comment: This link Here->https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByQnaVw7riBQMjNCUFh4ZlM4Y0E/edit?usp=sharing Will install web app for Microsoft office for Linux. I would suggest installing wine & just downloading regular office if you have a licensing for it!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use office online if you are not averse to spending a few bucks.

Answer (score 1):

There is Kingsoft's WPS Office. It's known for dealing very well with all the Microsoft Office formats. Unfortunately it can't handle ODF (LibreOffice) formats, so if you use LibreOffice you'll have to keep it.

You can download WPS Office from [this link](http://wps-community.org/downloads).

Select `wps-office_10.1.0.5460~a20p1_i386.deb` for Ubuntu 32-bit or `wps-office_10.1.0.5460~a20p1_amd64.deb` for 64-bit. After downloading, open the download location and double-click the .deb file. It will open in the Software Center, giving some details about the product and the option to install it.

Here's an image of WPS Writer running in Ubuntu.

[image: WPS Writer]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-801-Microsoft_Office_2010.html. You will basicly get a easy wine-installer for office 2010, running in Linux. Not possible with 2013 or 2016 yet.